# select input is not working? Using Single-page-application AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize

I have a single-page application and I have a problem loading things in my UI

So my index.html goes like this

```
html lang="en" ng-app="App" ng-controller="IndexController">
<head>
    <!-- CORE CSS-->
    <link href="css/materialize.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <link href="css/style.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <link href="css/custom/custom.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-utils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize-plugins/date_picker/picker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize-plugins/date_picker/picker.date.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/select2.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller/IndexController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="cyan">
*some navbar codes here*
<section id="content">
   <div ng-view>
   </div>
</section>
</body>
*some scripts here*
</html>
```

then I have my other pages like this

```
    <section id="content" ng-controller="DashboardController">
    *some codes here*
<select required id="names" ng-model="selectedName" ng-class="{invalid : validation.names}"  ng-options="x for x in names"></select>
     <div class="row">
                        <div ng-repeat="x in names">
                            {{x}}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s4"></div>
                        <div class="input-field col s4">
                            <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light white blue-text" ng-click="cancelRequest()">Cancel</a>
                            <a class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" ng-click="transaction()">Save</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s4"></div>
                    </div>
    </section>
```

the thing is I can't use select, radio boxes, check boxes and so on.

In my dashboard controller I have a list named `$scope.names` where the data are `$scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];` and it is declared in my init function

as you read you know it should work with the above code right? but...
[image]

it is showing with ng-repeat but not in ng-options

Can someone tell me what's wrong? I'm wracking my brains for hours already :(

I also have

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('select').material_select();
   });
```

and if I hard coded the `<option></option>` it wouldn't work unless I put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/angular-materialize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.min.js"></script>
```

Edit:

```
.controller('DashboardController', function ($http,$scope,$sessionStorage,StartingService,LogService,SweetAlert) {


    (function init() {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $sessionStorage.authenticate;
        $scope.isLogin = $sessionStorage.showLogin;
        $sessionStorage.currentBusiness;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('select').material_select();
            $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});

        });
```

Comment: where you  do `$('select').material_select();`??

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr inside my controller at init(), I have also tried it in the dashboard.html using <script></script>

Comment: Did you use  $onInit()  method?

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr no, please see my edited post

Answer (score 0):

So I think you should use $onInit() like this:

```
 controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    };
  },
```

Or  wrap you  select initialization on  $timeout:

```
 $timeout(() => $('select').material_select());
```

You don't need  wrap code to function

```
.controller('DashboardController', function ($http,$scope,$sessionStorage,StartingService,LogService,SweetAlert, $timeout) {
        $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = $sessionStorage.authenticate;
        $scope.isLogin = $sessionStorage.showLogin;
        $sessionStorage.currentBusiness;

        $timeout(function () {

            $('select').material_select();
            $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});

        });
```

Comment: its doesn't show the items. I used the syntax from w3schools from their first example of ng-options

Comment: Can you try to render options using ng-repeat ?